# Unable to compare and manage timedelta objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have following stub of code:

```
timeA = datetime.strptime(dateTimeStringA, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
least_time=timeA-timeA #Just to initialize the variable as timedelta object
most_time=least_time
timeB = datetime.strptime(dateTimeStringB, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
timeBA = timeB-timeA
...
print("timeBA",timeBA)
#0:00:00.919640
print("least_time",least_time)
#0:00:00
print("most_time",least_time)
#0:00:00

if timeBA < least_time:
    least_time = timeBA
if timeBA > most_time:
    most_time = timeBA

print("timeBA",timeBA)
#0:00:00.919640
print("least_time",least_time)
#0:00:00
print("most_time",least_time)
#0:00:00
```

Now in last I am printing three objects of same type, one is printed with microseconds, other two are not. And hence I am unable to see if my conditional assignments to these variables are working or not.

Comment: you could print the `.total_seconds()` of the timedelta objects to be sure

Comment: @MrFuppes only give `0.0`

Comment: since you initialize `least_time` and `most_time` as a timedelta of zero (`datetime.timedelta()`), I'd expect that. Anyway, you `print("most_time", least_time)`, did you mean `print("most_time" most_time)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The microseconds are not printed when they are zero.  So `0:00:00` means `0:00:00.000000`.

Comment: But in my opinion they shouldnt be zero, i edited by question for better explanation. You can see at this particular case `timeBA` has value in microseconds but `>0` so the second if condition should be true and `most_time = timeBA` but its not happening its remains 0.

Comment: What if you print `least_time.microseconds`?  Is that zero?

Comment: only prints `0` then.

Comment: Well then it's zero.